# Would a translation tool recommendation question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

One of my projects uses software developed in-house to gain translations from the community. It's functional, we're fully translated in 8 languages and partially translated in another 11, but I'd like to find out if there are better tools available.

I also think it would be useful to have a list of the best translation tools available as per the needs of an open source project (where some translators will make a small number of poor quality contributions).

Reading similar meta questions, it's unclear if this question is on topic.

Is it on topic? And if so, how can I ask the question to make sure it doesn't get (many) close/down votes?

Comment: Note: we do  have a similar question, but it's focused more on how to encourage people to *use* their translation tool, and less so about what the best translation tool is: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/807/how-can-i-encourage-translations-for-my-app/809#809

Comment: That's a bit of a red herring: while it reads like they're promoting their translation tool, they're not: http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/278/question-in-the-context-of-my-project-is-it-spam-to-put-a-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any questions that ask for software, libraries and apis, and other tools for open projects are off-topic. You can find a little bit of buzz about here:

[Should we rethink software recommendations?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/536/should-we-rethink-software-recommendations)

Comment: An answer with 3 upvotes (one of them was mine and I would like to remove it but it's not possible) is not an authoritative meta decision in my opinion.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert You can flag it for mod attention in that case :)

Answer (score 4):

I would say it's not; it's far more at home on website recommendations or software recommendations. I don't think we should do tool or service recommendations at all.

Comment: We don't have website recommendations yet... -_- |